# ODataService Type Provider error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: ssl, f#, odata, type-providers

> The type provider
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders'
>   reported an error: Error reading schema. The remote server returned an
>   error: (401) Unauthorized.

Is there a way to use the OData type provider with an OData service which requires a username and password?

[Static type parameters for the type provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362325.aspx):

- ServiceUri : string   The URI string for the OData service.
- LocalSchemaFile : string   The path to a file that contains the schema. This file is written by the type provider.
- ForceUpdate : bool   Requires that the direct connection to the service is available at design/compile time and the local service
  file is refreshed. The default value is true. When ForceUpdate is
  false, the provider reacts to changes in the LocalSchemaFile.
- ResolutionFolder : string   A folder to be used to resolve relative file paths at compile time. The default value is the folder that
  contains the project or script.
- DataServiceCollection : bool   Generates collections derived from DataServiceCollection. The default value is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but unfortunately it's not quite as slick, and you don't get compile-time validation, which is one of the nice benefits of type providers.

You need to grab the `$metadata` from your service and save it locally as a `.csdl` file, then use the `LocalSchemaFile` static parameter in your code.  You can then set credentials on the data context object in order to authenticate at runtime.

```
// download http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata to local file Metadata.csdl
type Northwind = ODataService<"http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/",
                              LocalSchemaFile="Metadata.csdl",
                              ForceUpdate=false>

let db = Northwind.GetDataContext()
db.Credentials <- System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials  // or whatever creds you need

// go party
```

Comment: I ended up using a .cdmx file I had from connecting using C#.  Just changed the file extension and it worked great.  Thanks!