# Compile error using F# WsdlService type provider

Tags: web-services, amazon-ec2, f#, wsdl, type-providers

I'm trying out type providers in F#. I've had some success using the WsdlService provider in the following fashion:

`type ec2 = WsdlService<"http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads/ec2.wsdl">`

but when I download that wsdl, rename it to .wsdlschema and supply it as a local schema according to the method specified in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18984629/313414):

```
type ec2 = WsdlService< ServiceUri="N/A", ForceUpdate = false, 
                          LocalSchemaFile = """C:\ec2.wsdlschema""">
```

Visual Studio emits an error message:

> The type provider
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders'
>   reported an error: Error: No valid input files specified. Specify
>   either metadata documents or assembly files

This message is **wrong**, since the file quite plainly is valid, as the previous example proves.

I've considered permissions issues, and I've repeated the same example from my user folder, making sure to grant full control to all users in both cases, as well as running VS as administrator.

Why does the F# compiler think the file isn't valid?

**edit #1:** I have confirmed that doing the same thing doesn't work for http://gis1.usgs.gov/arcgis/services/gap/GAP_Land_Cover_NVC_Class_Landuse/MapServer?wsdl either (a USGS vegetation-related API) whereas referencing the wsdl online works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmmm, it appears that the type provider is rather stubborn and inflexible in that it requires a true "wsdlschema" doc when using the `LocalSchemaFile` option.  A wsdlschema document can contain multiple .wsdl and .xsd files within it, wrapped in some XML to keep them separate.  I'm guessing this is some kind of standard thing in the Microsoft toolchain, but perhaps others (e.g. Amazon) don't expose stuff like this.

The first thing the TP attempts to do is unpack the wsdlschema file into its separate parts, and sadly it does the wrong thing if in fact there is no unpacking to be done. Then, when it tries to point svcutil.exe at the unpacked schema files to do the codegen, this dies with the error message you are seeing.

**Workaround**: Add the expected bits of XML into your file, and it will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceMetadataFiles>
  <ServiceMetadataFile name="ec2.wsdl">

  [body of your WSDL goes here]

  </ServiceMetadataFile>
</ServiceMetadataFiles>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! How did you work out what the problem was, out of curiosity? I couldn't find anything on Google that explained what a 'wsdlschema' was, and there's no documentation for the TypeProvider that tells you what it expects. This also doesn't match other users' experiences, where just supplying a wsdl works fine. I think I'm going to raise a bug report for this one.

Comment: I recall working through it when writing my answer for the question you linked above. Plus you can read the logic from the code directly.  See the `else` clause [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/TypeProvidersImpl.fs#L685) that is invoked when you use `LocalSchemaFile` and `ForceUpdate = false`.  You can see [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/TypeProvidersImpl.fs#L620) that `unpackFolder` assumes the wrapping XML is present.

Comment: And I don't think this could ever work with a local just-WSDL file.  Would be curious if you could point to an example.  It *does* work to point to a *remote* .wsdl in the URI - in that case there is some additional crawling logic in place.

Comment: The example I linked to in my original post describes *just* saving the WSDL then passing that path to `LocalSchemaFile`. Re-reading, it seems plausible from the language that @Tomas Petricek only *expects* it to work, and hasn't tried it.